How to print my library's or executable's build path?
I'm trying to print in my shell my library's or executable's build path using xmake. After build my library or executable file is located in build/linux/x86_64/release directory, I would like to print this directory in my shell using xmake's command e.g. print(os.projectdir()) prints in my shell root directory of my project. How can I do this?

print("$(buildir)")

or
import("core.project.config")
print(config.buildir())


Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.
